# SpreadSheetGear IWorksheet cells reading from multiple cells throwing exception

Tags: c#, spreadsheetgear

I am trying to read the cells from SpreadSheetGear IworkBook it's getting exception . Is it expected ?

```
    for (int i = wr; j <= er; i++) {
    for (int j = sc; j <= ec; j++)
                      {

                          var rng = worksheet.Range[i, j];
                          var cellData = GetCell(rng, worksheet);
                          row.c.Add(cellData.Index, cellData);
                      }
                      }

                      void GetCell (SpreadsheetGear.IRange rng,SpreadsheetGear.IWorksheet worksheet) {
                      // CPU bound task

                       if (rng.Locked)
                    {
                        var locked = 1;
                    }
                      }


===================

Parllelism Code
Parallel.For (sr ,er+1 ,i =>
{
for (int j = sc; j <= ec; j++)
                  {

                      var rng = worksheet.Range[i, j];
                      var cellData = GetCell(rng, worksheet);
                      row.c.Add(cellData.Index, cellData);
                  }
                  }

                  void GetCell (SpreadsheetGear.IRange rng,SpreadsheetGear.IWorksheet worksheet) {
                  // CPU bound task

                   if (rng.Locked)
                {
                    var locked = 1;
                }
                  }
```

I am trying to parallelise the CPU bound task But the it throwing exception when i tried to use parallelism below block throwing exception

```
 if (rng.Locked)
                    {
                        var locked = 1;
                    }
                      }
```

Comment: You'll need to provide much more specific information to get any helpful feedback.  Please provide more details on the code involved, cell values or other relevant information on these cells, the exception you are getting, etc.

Comment: I edited my question with full details.please have a look

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions for this sort of scenario would be expected, as you cannot parallelize this kind of work on a workbook.  In the case of your parallel code, multiple threads are accessing the workbook simultaneously, which is not supported and so eventually leads to some unexpected / bad internal state and ultimately to the exception you are seeing.

SpreadsheetGear does support accessing workbooks from multiple threads, but this comes with a big caveat: each thread must do its work between calls to IWorkbookSet.[GetLock](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IWorkbookSet~GetLock.html)() / [ReleaseLock](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IWorkbookSet~ReleaseLock.html)(), which guarantee that only one thread will access the workbook at any given time.  So for your task of parallelizing work, this API does you no good since using GetLock() / ReleaseLock() would effectively turn your parallel task back to a serial one.  Bottom-line, there is no way to safely parallelize this sort of task with SpreadsheetGear.

Comment: I am Just trying to read from IRange (cell properties) multiple reads also not supported by Irange? If it's the case, Clone IRange object and read the properties from the cloned object. is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "multiple reads" on an IRange, can you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry not multiple reads. Just i am trying to read properties from IRange. Read from multiple threads at a time also not supported? If it's the case, Clone IRange object and read the properties from the cloned object. is it possible?

Comment: Multi-threaded access of any kind (read or write) is not possible unless you use GetLock() and ReleaseLock() which, as indicated previously, does you no good as far as performance goes for your task.  You can't clone an IRange, but putting that aside, even if you could it would do you no good, as both IRange object would still be part of the same underlying workbook (and more specifically IWorkbookSet object) which can't be accessed simultaneously by multiple threads.